# A mechanism of the CoffeeScript language

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Before using any library, framework etc. in JavaScript, I am interested in it mechanism.
I would like to find out how **CoffeeScript**  works.

My assumption:

1st step: compiler gets string from:

```
  <script type="text/coffeescript"></script>
```

2nd: it creates a js-code like a string:

```
 it = "test" -> "var it = 'test';"
```

and the last step compiler uses eval() to implement a code.

P.S.:
 Why does it become popular? 
 It has an influence upon performance, after all we spend a lot of time to execute .coffee files.

Comment: CoffeeScript files can be compiled **server-side** which means the browser only sees js files (apart when debugging if you provide .map files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to compile CoffeeScript code server-side, and then link JavaScript in your HTML files. This is normally performed using the `coffeee` command line utility, but you can also find build systems that take care of it for you, such as Grunt, Brunch, etc. You can also write `Makefile`s or simple shell scripts to take care of this for you.

When using some of the build systems and the `coffee` tool, you have an option of having the tools monitor your CoffeeScript sources and recompile as soon as you save them. This can be quite handy. Look at the 'watch' feature in the documentation.

My guess for CoffeeScript popularity is that it gives you an arguably nicer syntax. Personally, I find the greatest merit of CoffeeScript is added syntactic sugar like list comprehensions and the fact it treats everything as an expression (e.g., ability to return for loops or if-else blocks from functions). You will also find languages that take this idea even further, like Coco, LiveScript.

One thing to note is that CoffeeScript is not an interpreted language. It's transpiled (compiled into another language) and then executed by the target runtime (JavaScript engine). Because of this, it has the same performance characteristics as equivalent JavaScript code. Whether you can manually write more performant code is another issue. You probably can. At any rate, it's a bit silly to talk about CoffeeScript 'performance'. As for the performance of compiled CoffeeScript, with good knowledge of JavaScript, you can probably optimize here and there, but I haven't had a need to do it ever.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of using Coffee Script is to compile in as a step in your build process. So you would write Coffee Script, then compile it to plain Javascript, and then use that in your web app.

This carries no runtime cost, because browser will load only Javascript, i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="compiled-js-file.js"></script>
```

You can use `coffee` command directly to compile, or some more fancy build systems such as [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

You can see [Coffe Script](http://coffeescript.org/) website to see what features it has (this is what attracts developers). Most useful, in my opinion, are:

- array syntax for functions (JS will support it in ES6)
- existential operator to protect you from null value errors
- classes (also present in ES6)
- destructuring assignment

Also, this means then when you are debugging such a webapp, you will not be able to see where exactly the error is (or setup break points in coffee sources). Fortunately, we have [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) for exactly that problem.